# Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, r-faq

I have some trouble to convert my `data.frame` from a wide table to a long table.
At the moment it looks like this:

```
Code Country        1950    1951    1952    1953    1954
AFG  Afghanistan    20,249  21,352  22,532  23,557  24,555
ALB  Albania        8,097   8,986   10,058  11,123  12,246
```

Now I would like to transform this `data.frame` into a long `data.frame`.
Something like this:

```
Code Country        Year    Value
AFG  Afghanistan    1950    20,249
AFG  Afghanistan    1951    21,352
AFG  Afghanistan    1952    22,532
AFG  Afghanistan    1953    23,557
AFG  Afghanistan    1954    24,555
ALB  Albania        1950    8,097
ALB  Albania        1951    8,986
ALB  Albania        1952    10,058
ALB  Albania        1953    11,123
ALB  Albania        1954    12,246
```

I have looked at and already tried using the `melt()` and the `reshape()` functions
as some people were suggesting in similar questions.
However, so far I only get messy results.

If it is possible I would like to do it with the `reshape()` function since
it looks a little bit nicer to handle.

Comment: Don't know if that was the problem, but the functions in the reshape package are melt and cast (and recast.)

Comment: And the reshape package has been superseded by reshape2.

Comment: And now reshape2 has been superseded by tidyr.

Comment: And now `tidyr`'s `gather` and `spread` have been replaced by `pivot_*` functions.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

`reshape()` takes a while to get used to, just as `melt`/`cast`. Here is a solution with reshape, assuming your data frame is called `d`:

```
reshape(d, 
        direction = "long",
        varying = list(names(d)[3:7]),
        v.names = "Value",
        idvar = c("Code", "Country"),
        timevar = "Year",
        times = 1950:1954)
```

Answer (score 231):

Two alternative solutions:

**1) With [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):**

You can use the [`melt`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/melt.data.table.html) function:

```
library(data.table)
long <- melt(setDT(wide), id.vars = c("Code","Country"), variable.name = "year")
```

which gives:

> ```
> > long
>     Code     Country year  value
>  1:  AFG Afghanistan 1950 20,249
>  2:  ALB     Albania 1950  8,097
>  3:  AFG Afghanistan 1951 21,352
>  4:  ALB     Albania 1951  8,986
>  5:  AFG Afghanistan 1952 22,532
>  6:  ALB     Albania 1952 10,058
>  7:  AFG Afghanistan 1953 23,557
>  8:  ALB     Albania 1953 11,123
>  9:  AFG Afghanistan 1954 24,555
> 10:  ALB     Albania 1954 12,246
> ```

Some alternative notations:

```
melt(setDT(wide), id.vars = 1:2, variable.name = "year")
melt(setDT(wide), measure.vars = 3:7, variable.name = "year")
melt(setDT(wide), measure.vars = as.character(1950:1954), variable.name = "year")
```

**2) With [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr):**

Use [`pivot_longer()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html):

```
library(tidyr)

long <- wide %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = `1950`:`1954`, 
    names_to = "year",
    values_to = "value"
)
```

Note:

- `names_to` and `values_to` default to `"name"` and `"value"`, respectively, so you could write this extra-succinctly as `` wide %>% pivot_longer(`1950`:`1954`) ``.
- The `cols` argument uses the highly flexible [tidyselect DSL](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html), so you can select the same columns using a negative selection (`!c(Code, Country)`), a selection helper(`starts_with("19")`; `matches("^\\d{4}$")`), numeric indices (`3:7`), and more.
- `tidyr::pivot_longer()` is the successor to `tidyr::gather()` and `reshape2::melt()`, which are no longer under development.

**Transforming values**

Another problem with the data is that the values will be read by R as character-values (as a result of the `,` in the numbers). You can repair with `gsub` and `as.numeric`, either before reshaping:

```
long$value <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", long$value))
```

Or during reshaping, with `data.table` or `tidyr`:

```
# data.table
long <- melt(setDT(wide),
             id.vars = c("Code","Country"),
             variable.name = "year")[, value := as.numeric(gsub(",", "", value))]

# tidyr
long <- wide %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = `1950`:`1954`, 
    names_to = "year",
    values_to = "value",
    values_transform = ~ as.numeric(gsub(",", "", .x))
  )
```

---

**Data:**

```
wide <- read.table(text="Code Country        1950    1951    1952    1953    1954
AFG  Afghanistan    20,249  21,352  22,532  23,557  24,555
ALB  Albania        8,097   8,986   10,058  11,123  12,246", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: great answer, just one more tiny reminder : do not put any variables other than `id` and`time` in your data frame, `melt` could not tell what you want to do in this case.

Comment: @JasonGoal Could you elaborate on that? As I'm interpreting you comment, it shouldn't be a problem. Just specify both the `id.vars` and the `measure.vars`.

Comment: ,then that's good for me, don't know `id.vars` and the `measure.vars` can be specified in the first alternative,sorry for the mess, its my fault.

Comment: Sorry to necro this post - could someone explain to me *why* 3 works? I've tested it and it works, but I don't understand what dplyr is doing when it sees `-c(var1, var2)`...

Comment: @ReputableMisnomer When [tag:tidyr] sees `-c(var1, var2)` it omits these variables when transforming the data from wide to long format.

Comment: Ah wow - what a neat trick. Truly a time saver. Was so resistant to move to the `tidyverse()` yet it surprises me every day...

Comment: According to the [tidyverse blog](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/09/tidyr-1-0-0/)  `gather` is now retired and as been replaced by `pivot_longer`. They state: "New `pivot_longer()` and `pivot_wider()` provide modern alternatives to `spread()` and `gather()`. They have been carefully redesigned to be easier to learn and remember, and include many new features. spread() and gather() won’t go away, but they’ve been retired which means that they’re no longer under active development."

Answer (score 63):

With `tidyr_1.0.0`, another option is `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df1, -c(Code, Country), values_to = "Value", names_to = "Year")
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#   Code  Country     Year  Value 
#   <fct> <fct>       <chr> <fct> 
# 1 AFG   Afghanistan 1950  20,249
# 2 AFG   Afghanistan 1951  21,352
# 3 AFG   Afghanistan 1952  22,532
# 4 AFG   Afghanistan 1953  23,557
# 5 AFG   Afghanistan 1954  24,555
# 6 ALB   Albania     1950  8,097 
# 7 ALB   Albania     1951  8,986 
# 8 ALB   Albania     1952  10,058
# 9 ALB   Albania     1953  11,123
#10 ALB   Albania     1954  12,246
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Code = structure(1:2, .Label = c("AFG", "ALB"), class = "factor"), 
    Country = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Afghanistan", "Albania"
    ), class = "factor"), `1950` = structure(1:2, .Label = c("20,249", 
    "8,097"), class = "factor"), `1951` = structure(1:2, .Label = c("21,352", 
    "8,986"), class = "factor"), `1952` = structure(2:1, .Label = c("10,058", 
    "22,532"), class = "factor"), `1953` = structure(2:1, .Label = c("11,123", 
    "23,557"), class = "factor"), `1954` = structure(2:1, .Label = c("12,246", 
    "24,555"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: This needs more upvotes. According to the [Tidyverse Blog](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/09/tidyr-1-0-0/)  `gather` is being retired and `pivot_longer` is now the correct way to accomplish this.

Comment: @EvanRosica only until they decide to change the function again :p

Comment: What does `-c(...)` do? It looks like deleting a column but it is not. Can you please explain the syntaxis?

Answer (score 39):

Using *reshape* package:

```
#data
x <- read.table(textConnection(
"Code Country        1950    1951    1952    1953    1954
AFG  Afghanistan    20,249  21,352  22,532  23,557  24,555
ALB  Albania        8,097   8,986   10,058  11,123  12,246"), header=TRUE)

library(reshape)

x2 <- melt(x, id = c("Code", "Country"), variable_name = "Year")
x2[,"Year"] <- as.numeric(gsub("X", "" , x2[,"Year"]))
```

Answer (score 37):

Since this answer is tagged with [r-faq](/questions/tagged/r-faq), I felt it would be useful to share another alternative from base R: `stack`.

Note, however, that `stack` does not work with `factor`s--it only works if `is.vector` is `TRUE`, and from the documentation for `is.vector`, we find that:

> `is.vector` returns `TRUE` if x is a vector of the specified mode having no attributes *other than names*. It returns `FALSE` otherwise.

I'm using the sample data [from @Jaap's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25856135/1270695), where the values in the year columns are `factor`s.

Here's the `stack` approach:

```
cbind(wide[1:2], stack(lapply(wide[-c(1, 2)], as.character)))
##    Code     Country values  ind
## 1   AFG Afghanistan 20,249 1950
## 2   ALB     Albania  8,097 1950
## 3   AFG Afghanistan 21,352 1951
## 4   ALB     Albania  8,986 1951
## 5   AFG Afghanistan 22,532 1952
## 6   ALB     Albania 10,058 1952
## 7   AFG Afghanistan 23,557 1953
## 8   ALB     Albania 11,123 1953
## 9   AFG Afghanistan 24,555 1954
## 10  ALB     Albania 12,246 1954
```

Comment: You've saved package developers everywhere 

Answer (score 11):

Here is another example showing the use of `gather` from `tidyr`. You can select the columns to `gather` either by removing them individually (as I do here), or by including the years you want explicitly.

Note that, to handle the commas (and X's added if `check.names = FALSE` is not set), I am also using `dplyr`'s mutate with `parse_number` from `readr` to convert the text values back to numbers. These are all part of the `tidyverse` and so can be loaded together with `library(tidyverse)`

```
wide %>%
  gather(Year, Value, -Code, -Country) %>%
  mutate(Year = parse_number(Year)
         , Value = parse_number(Value))
```

Returns:

```
   Code     Country Year Value
1   AFG Afghanistan 1950 20249
2   ALB     Albania 1950  8097
3   AFG Afghanistan 1951 21352
4   ALB     Albania 1951  8986
5   AFG Afghanistan 1952 22532
6   ALB     Albania 1952 10058
7   AFG Afghanistan 1953 23557
8   ALB     Albania 1953 11123
9   AFG Afghanistan 1954 24555
10  ALB     Albania 1954 12246
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a [sqldf](/questions/tagged/sqldf) solution:

```
sqldf("Select Code, Country, '1950' As Year, `1950` As Value From wide
        Union All
       Select Code, Country, '1951' As Year, `1951` As Value From wide
        Union All
       Select Code, Country, '1952' As Year, `1952` As Value From wide
        Union All
       Select Code, Country, '1953' As Year, `1953` As Value From wide
        Union All
       Select Code, Country, '1954' As Year, `1954` As Value From wide;")
```

To make the query without typing in everything, you can use the following:

<sup>Thanks to G. Grothendieck for implementing it.</sup>

```
ValCol <- tail(names(wide), -2)

s <- sprintf("Select Code, Country, '%s' As Year, `%s` As Value from wide", ValCol, ValCol)
mquery <- paste(s, collapse = "\n Union All\n")

cat(mquery) #just to show the query
 #> Select Code, Country, '1950' As Year, `1950` As Value from wide
 #>  Union All
 #> Select Code, Country, '1951' As Year, `1951` As Value from wide
 #>  Union All
 #> Select Code, Country, '1952' As Year, `1952` As Value from wide
 #>  Union All
 #> Select Code, Country, '1953' As Year, `1953` As Value from wide
 #>  Union All
 #> Select Code, Country, '1954' As Year, `1954` As Value from wide

sqldf(mquery)
```

```
 #>    Code     Country Year  Value
 #> 1   AFG Afghanistan 1950 20,249
 #> 2   ALB     Albania 1950  8,097
 #> 3   AFG Afghanistan 1951 21,352
 #> 4   ALB     Albania 1951  8,986
 #> 5   AFG Afghanistan 1952 22,532
 #> 6   ALB     Albania 1952 10,058
 #> 7   AFG Afghanistan 1953 23,557
 #> 8   ALB     Albania 1953 11,123
 #> 9   AFG Afghanistan 1954 24,555
 #> 10  ALB     Albania 1954 12,246
```

Unfortunately, I don't think that `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` would work for `R` `SQLite`. If you want to write up your query in a more sophisticated manner, you can also take a look at these posts:

- [Using `sprintf` writing up sql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40432590/r-sprintf-list-of-variables-of-mixed-type)
- [Pass variables to `sqldf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547950/how-can-i-pass-r-variable-into-sqldf)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `cdata` package, which uses the concept of (transformation) control table:

```
# data
wide <- read.table(text="Code Country        1950    1951    1952    1953    1954
AFG  Afghanistan    20,249  21,352  22,532  23,557  24,555
ALB  Albania        8,097   8,986   10,058  11,123  12,246", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)

library(cdata)
# build control table
drec <- data.frame(
    Year=as.character(1950:1954),
    Value=as.character(1950:1954),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
drec <- cdata::rowrecs_to_blocks_spec(drec, recordKeys=c("Code", "Country"))

# apply control table
cdata::layout_by(drec, wide)
```

I am currently exploring that package and find it quite accessible. It is designed for much more complicated transformations and includes the backtransformation. There is [a tutorial](https://win-vector.com/2019/04/16/controlling-data-layout-with-cdata/) available.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two options in base R (use `x=unlist(df)` instead of `x=c(m)` when the input is a dataframe and not a matrix):

```
> m=matrix(sample(1:100,6),3,dimnames=list(2021:2023,c("male","female")))
> m
     male female
2021   89     42
2022   39     96
2023   26     40
> cbind(expand.grid(dimnames(m)),x=c(m))
  Var1   Var2  x
1 2021   male 89
2 2022   male 39
3 2023   male 26
4 2021 female 42
5 2022 female 96
6 2023 female 40
> data.frame(row=rownames(m),col=colnames(m)[col(m)],x=c(m))
   row    col  x
1 2021   male 89
2 2022   male 39
3 2023   male 26
4 2021 female 42
5 2022 female 96
6 2023 female 40
```

A third option is to use `as.table` followed by `as.data.frame`, but it converts the row and column names to factors, and if your input is a dataframe then you have to convert it to a matrix first:

```
> as.data.frame(as.table(m))
  Var1   Var2 Freq
1 2021   male   89
2 2022   male   39
3 2023   male   26
4 2021 female   42
5 2022 female   96
6 2023 female   40
> as.data.frame(as.table(m))|>sapply(class)
     Var1      Var2      Freq
 "factor"  "factor" "integer"
> d=as.data.frame(m)
> as.data.frame(as.table(d))
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.data.frame': cannot coerce to a table
> as.data.frame(as.table(as.matrix(d)))
  Var1   Var2 Freq
1 2021   male   89
2 2022   male   39
3 2023   male   26
4 2021 female   42
5 2022 female   96
6 2023 female   40
```

A fourth option is to use `stack`, but it converts the rownames and column names to factors, and the column names get converted to an Rle factor when the input is a matrix (but not when the input is a dataframe):

```
> stack(m)
DataFrame with 6 rows and 3 columns
       row    col     value
  <factor>  <Rle> <integer>
1     2021   male        89
2     2022   male        39
3     2023   male        26
4     2021 female        42
5     2022 female        96
6     2023 female        40
```

When the input for `stack` is a dataframe, the rownames don't get included as a column so you have to `cbind` them:

```
> d=as.data.frame(m);cbind(row=rownames(d),stack(d))
   row values    ind
1 2021     89   male
2 2022     39   male
3 2023     26   male
4 2021     42 female
5 2022     96 female
6 2023     40 female
```